# How to write ElasticSearch query for Firebase?

Tags: android, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flashlight

Can someone show me how to correctly write queries ElasticSearch on Android?
Currently I'm doing this in that way:

```
    Map<String, Object> matched = new HashMap<>();
    matched.put("userName", "skye");
    Map<String, Object> match = new HashMap<>();
    match.put("match", matched);
    Map<String, Object> must = new HashMap<>();
    must.put("must", match);
    Map<String, Object> query = new HashMap<>();
    query.put("bool", must);
    Map<String, Object> q = new HashMap<>();
    q.put("index","firebase");
    q.put("type", "user");
    q.put("query", query);
    DatabaseReference ref = App.getDatabase().getReference("search");
    String key = ref.child("request").push().getKey();
    ref.child("request").child(key).setValue(q);
```

Here is data structure:

```
users: {
 uid: {
    "userName": "",
    ....
   }...
}
```

And config.js paths:

```
   {
      path:  "users",
      index: "firebase",
      type:  "User"
   }
```

When I execute above the code, it's returns 0 total values. 
Am I doing it right?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990344/how-query-firebase-with-elasticsearch-and-flashlight ?

Comment: @Val a little, now I have another problem... https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/issues/82